# Separate User Authentication Module

Tags: web-services, architecture, module

At my organization, we're moving towards a modular software architecture.. We're still in the beginning phases, and are currently working on the User Authentication (UA) module.

I'm looking for information on best practices in terms of a User Authentication module.

My current notion is the following:

- Client queries UA module with login details
- UA module checks login details.  If they are valid, the UA module creates & stores access token, associating the token with the validated user's unique ID.
- The token is sent back to the client.  Client stores the token.
- Whenever the client requires authentication, it queries the UA module with the token.  The UA module returns the user's unique ID if the token is valid, or returns an error code if the token is invalid.

I would appreciate any criticism on those methods.

I'm also interested in knowing how to deal with the accumulation of tokens.  Obviously if a user chooses to log out, the token is removed.

My notion is that tokens should have expiry dates associated with them, and a worker process should clean these tokens up at a regular interval.  Is this the right way to go about things?

Please comment!  Reference documents are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the token in a DB field along with issue timestamp, with an one-to-one mapping with the client ID. So when you have reissue a token, you overwrite the old one. And when user logs out, null out the token.

When the User sends a request with the token, see if the token is past expiry date (i.e. current time > issue time + expiry time period). This would save you from running a Worker to clean up old tokens.

Comment: Wouldn't the DB grow to have too many tokens without cleaning them up?  That's where I'm confused

Comment: I guess you missed the one-to-one part, essentially, assign just one token to one client at any given point in time. So an issuance of new token cleans up the old token, and you can never have more tokens than you have clients.